# Stripe.setPublishableKey is not a function Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am upgrading my stripe js version from v1 to v3 But I am getting an error that Stripe.setPublishableKey is not a function??

What is the solution for this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Stripe.setPublishableKey` was the function available in v1 and v2. The function changed for v3 and this is covered in details in the documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-function

The code should now be:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXX');
```

The rest of the code would change completely too so you should look at the migration guide: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating

Comment: @ koopajah got stuck in stripe.createToken is not a function

Comment: @Ceaser have you read the docs for this? Like you can't just include v3 and hope it works, every line of code has changed. You should read the migration docs I linked

Comment: @ koopajah yes, i have gone through the docs. read it carefully then too i am not able to get some things